# How to move files including full path to a subfolder?

Tags: bash, find, xargs

I've got a `public` folder that includes `.html` and non `.html` files in its root and subfolders. I need to move all non `.html` files to a subfolder of the `public` folder, e.g. to `public/assets`, preserving their full path.

So far I got something like this:

```
mkdir -p public/assets
find public -type f -not -name "*.html" -print0 | xargs -0I{} mv {} public/assets/
```

It doesn't work correctly, because it doesn't move files with full path, e.g. if there's a file `public/foo/bar.js`, it will be moved to `public/assets/bar.js` and not into `public/assets/foo/bar.js`.

I also tried another version:

```
mkdir -p public/assets
find public -type f -not -name "*.html" | sed 's#\(public\)\(.*\)#\1\2 public/assets\2#' | xargs -I% mv %
```

but it complains about incorrect syntax of `mv` command. I pass only one parameter to it, but after running `sed` it consists of 2 paths separated with one space, so I hoped it will treat it as 2 parameters.

It would be also great, if there was a way to remove empty folders after moving all files, but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using rsync for this. Also, I would use a folder in a different location as destination. That folder can then be copied back to your public folder.

```
mkdir /tmp/assets

rsync -r --include="*/" --exclude="*.html" --include="*" --prune-empty-dirs public/* /tmp/assets

mv /tmp/assets public/assets
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to add `--remove-source-files` to move files. 

If I add `--exclude=public/assets/*` would it be possible to not create the temp folder?

Comment: Yes, it could work. However, I would recommend to work with a different directory. It is an anti-pattern to change the source while you are still analyzing it. It will save you trouble later on